# NSCheckingResult Range Property not set to {NSNotfound,0}?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

From looking at the docs for `NSTextCheckingResult` I was under the impression that if no match in a `NSRegularExpression` search was found the range property for `NSCheckingResult` would be set to `{NSNotFound,0}`

From my test below I am finding that if no match is found `NSCheckingResult` range is set to `{0,0}`. Its a small point, but I just wanted to clarify my understanding of how this is working.

```
// REGEXPRESSION  
NSString *textBuffer = @"1234567890";
NSString *pattern = @"(([A-Z]+))";
NSRegularExpression *regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regExp firstMatchInString:textBuffer options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [textBuffer length])];

// ERROR CHECK
if([match range].location == NSNotFound) NSLog(@"Match Not found");
NSLog(@"location: %d", [match range].location);
NSLog(@"length  : %d", [match range].length);

// OUTPUT
location: 0
length  : 0
```

EDIT:
In this example `NSTextCheckingResult *match` is being set to `nil`, which is probably why location and length are returning zero (message to nil object).

```
if(!match) NSLog(@"Match Not Found");
```

I am therefore guessing that `NSNotFound` is only returned when there are multiple capture groups where it represent an empty group.

Comment: Yes it's because of the null match. `{NSNotFound, 0}` can be returned by `rangeAtIndex:` for the group which didn't participate in the match.

Comment: @hoha if you move your comment into an answer, then fuzzygoat could accept it and move this question out of the Unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's because of the null match. `{NSNotFound, 0}` can be returned by `rangeAtIndex:` for the group which didn't participate in the match.